# l'Hopitals Rule for limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

To use the l'Hopitals rule to evaluate the limit of

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \dfrac{1 - x + \ln x}{1 + \cos(\pi x)}$

*I get an undefined answer!*

My working is:

If we let:

$f(x) = 1 - x + \ln x$, then $f'(x)=\frac1x-1$

$g(x)= 1 + \cos(\pi x)$, then $g'(x)=-\pi \sin(\pi x)$

As l'Hopital rule states $f'(x)/g'(x)$

My answer would be  $\dfrac{\frac1x-1}{-\pi\sin(\pi x)}$

And substituting in $x=1$ for the limit gives $\dfrac{0}{-\pi\sin(\pi)}$

Is this correct? Is my method right? 
Can this be undefined?

Thanks

Comment: What is loge(x) ?

Comment: After one round of L'Hospital, the limit of top and bottom is $0$. Do another round!

Comment: @NeilRoy ojando meant $\log_e(x)$ , the natural logarithm, and should  learn how to use MathJax so as to make things readable.

Comment: Yup i just edited the question...Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: @NeilRoy Do you mean it serious ? $\log_e(x)$ is the logarithm of x with base e.

Comment: @calculus no actually i thought it to be something else! Before editing it looked like "loge"...My bad!

Comment: You are supposed to use the rule till you get an expression which doesn't come out as undefined when you substitute the limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the rule twice.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{1-x+\ln x}{1+\cos\pi x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{-1+1/x}{-\pi \sin\pi x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{1-x}{-\pi x\sin\pi x}$

use the rule once again:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{-1}{-\pi(\sin\pi x+\pi x\cos\pi x)}=-1/\pi^2$.

Comment: It would have been better to leave it as $\frac{-1+\frac{1}{x}}{-\pi\sin(\pi x)}$, and then differentiate top and bottom (no bringing $x$ downstairs). And the answer is not quite right.

Comment: limit should be $-1/\pi^2$

Comment: @DrakeMarquis: It would be $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{-1}{-\pi(\sin\pi x+x\pi \cos\pi x)}=\frac{-1}{\pi^2}$$.

Comment: @Integrator You're correct!

Comment: @DrakeMarquis how do you get Pi sqaured on the denominator? How does the rest cancel out?

Comment: @ojando In the first expression, you get one $\pi$ by differentiating $\cos\pi x$. The second $\pi$ comes from the second expression which was obtained by differentiating $\sin\pi x$.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to find $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1-x + \ln x}{1+\cos( \pi x)} ,$$ i will do a change of variable $x = 1 + h.$ now we have for $h$ small, $$1-x+\ln x = 1 -1 - h+ \ln (1 + h) = \ln(1 + h) - h = -\frac 12 h^2 + \cdots  $$ and 
$$1+\cos \pi x = 1+\cos (\pi + \pi h) =1 - \cos(\pi h) = \frac 12 \pi^2h^2 + \cdots $$  therefore 
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1-x + \ln x}{1+\cos( \pi x)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+h) - h}{1 - \cos(\pi h)} = -\frac{1}{\pi^2}$$

Comment: i dont understand how you can let x=1+h ? can you please clarify why?

Comment: and where has any differentiation taken place?

Comment: the reason for the change of variable is to make the limiting variable always approach zero!

Comment: then how is this still using l'hopitals rule? thanks

Comment: if you want to use l'hospitals, then use it on the second limit.